# How do you require certain properties from the URI of the request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very simple model:

```
public class FoobarGETRequestModel {
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

It's being used for binding like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateModel] //This is a custom attribute for handling validation errors
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Foobar([FromUri]FoobarGETRequestModel model) {
    ...
}
```

If I make a request to `/api/controller/foobar` (notice I'm not providing an `Id` parameter), the `ModelState.IsValid` property always returns true (from both an action filter and from within the method above).

How do I bind via the URI and still leverage the frameworks `ModelState` validation?

**Edit**: Here is what `ValidateModel` looks like:

```
if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false) {
    var responseObject = new FooApiExceptionResponse() {
        Errors = actionContext.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
    };

    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, responseObject);
}
```

Comment: So you're saying the `Id` property is not being set (not even in a default construtor? Or the default value in the routing?) and the model state is still valid although the `Id` is supossed to be `null`?

Comment: @rdoubleui - Correct.  In fact, from debugging, the `model` object is actually null.

Comment: What does `ValidateModel` look like?

Comment: @rdoubleui - I updated my post with `ValidateModel`.  As you can see it's very simple; simply take the errors from the `ModelState` and put them into an object for a response.

Comment: If you're saying the `model` object is null, then there's another problem to be fixed first, no?

Comment: That's why the validation might be working, as the `required` annotation is only taken into account if the (overlaying) object is not null as the [docs indicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your RouteTable? If you are telling routetable that your "id" parameter is optional in default route, this could occur.